# Implement "same" padding for convolution operations with dilation > 1, in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, padding, dilation

I am using Pytorch 1.8.1 and although I know the newer version has padding "same" option, for some reasons I do not want to upgrade it. To implement same padding for CNN with stride 1 and dilation >1, I put padding as follows:

```
 padding=(dilation*(cnn_kernel_size[0]-1)//2, dilation*(cnn_kernel_size[1]-1)//2))
```

According to the [Pytorch document](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.8.1/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html?highlight=conv2d#torch.nn.Conv2d), I expected the input and output size will be the same, but it did not happen!

It is written in Pytorch document that:

```
Hout​=⌊( Hin​ + 2×padding[0] − dilation[0]×(kernel_size[0]−1) −1) /stride[0] ​+ 1⌋

Wout​=⌊( Win​ + 2×padding[1] − dilation[1]×(kernel_size[1]−1) −1) /stride[1] + 1⌋
```

The input of torch.nn.Conv2d was with the shape of (1,1,625,513)
which based on the [Conv2d pytorch document](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.8.1/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html?highlight=conv2d#torch.nn.Conv2d), indicates batch size = 1, C in = 1, H in = 625 and Win = 513

and after using:

- 64 filters
- kernel size of (15,15)
- stride = (1,1)
- dilation =5
- padding =(35,35)

Putting those values in the formulas above gives us:

```
Hout​=⌊(625 ​+ 2×35 −5×(15−1) −1) /1 ​+1⌋=⌊(625 ​+ 70 −5×14 -1) + 1⌋=625

Wout​=⌊(513 ​+ 2×35 −5×(15−1) −1) /1 ​+1⌋=⌊(513 ​+ 70 −5×14 -1) + 1⌋=513
```

However, the given output shape by pytorch was (1,64,681,569)

I can understand the value of 1 and C out = 64.  But I don't know why H out and W out are not the same as H in and W in? Does anyone has any explanation that can help?

Comment: unable to reproduce. please provide a minimal example that reproduces your error.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out! The reason that I ended up with the wrong dimension was that I didn't put a numeric value for padding. I gave it the numeric value of dilation and based on that it calculate itself the value for padding as

padding=(dilation*(cnn_kernel_size[0]-1)//2, dilation*(cnn_kernel_size[1]-1)//2))

I think Pytorch needs to be given the numeric value of padding because when I change my code and gave the network the value of padding and calculate the dilation based on padding (Dilation = (2*padding)/(kernel size -1) I got the right output shape.

Answer (score 1):

I think your calculations are correct. The padding should be 35 pixels.
For some reason, I am unable to reproduce the output shape you report.

Testing this, yield the desired output size:

```py
import torch

conv = torch.nn.Conv2d(1, 64, kernel_size=15, dilation=5, padding=35, stride=1)
conv(torch.rand(1, 1, 625, 513)).shape
```

Yields

> ```
> torch.Size([1, 64, 625, 513])
> ```

As expected.